# Where should I put logic in the Java tab layouts

Tags: android, material-design

I have 2 fragments each fragments has a different java logic. Where should i put the java logic? if i  did put it in the fragments,then error message displays :

`cannot resolve method findViewById, Cannont resolve method getApplicationContext`

[image]

Comment: Share some code in the question instead of a screenshot. `getApplicationContext` cannot be resolved in a fragment, because a fragment is not a context. Use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appear that you did not inflate the view correctly, change your code to be something like this :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);
     mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mButton );
     list_content = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
     ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);   
     return view;
}
```

and you should use **'`getActivity()`'** method for context not **'`This`'** .

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate the view on the oncreateview make a view field like this :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout..., container, false);
```

and return with this view.
After that with this variable you can reach the findViewById, like

```
view.findViewById
```

Instead of **getApplicationContext** you can use **getContext** in fragment.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can find other view's Id's in your fragment like this.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,container,false);
                tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

                return view;
            }
```